# A call to std::cin >> does not block

Tags: c++

I have a C++ console application that takes input from user by displaying a menu and then acting on it. Everything works fine when the user inputs integer values but when the user inputs a '**?**' (which I wanted to handle as a 'display help' option) the code starts looping infinitely and does not block on the `std::cin>>` call. Is this expected? What am I missing here?

```
int queryAction()
{
  while(1) {
    char selection;
    std::cout << "Action: ";
    std::cin >> selection;

    switch(selection)
    {
      //Some code that acts on the selection
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Follow Up:**
If I add `std::cin.clear()` before the call to `cin>>` all is good. I guess my follow up question is why is an error state set on input that should be a valid ascii character?

Comment: Can we see what's in your switch.

Comment: Is that while loop intended?

Comment: By the code starts looping - Do you mean you see "Action: " outputted constantly to your screen? Otherwise the code is blocking inside your switch statement.

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote to handle the '?' case?

Comment: Assuming there is no loop within the switch statement, It must have encountered an error with the input stream. You need to reset and ignore using `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(..)`.

Comment: Your fundamental error of thinking is in ignoring the result of the input operation. How do you expect to handle input sanely if you don't care about whether you succeeded in reading it?

Comment: Yes the while loop was intended and the switch has some trivial method calls (I'm saying trivial b/c when I comment them out the same issue occurs)

Comment: Do you need to flush the `cout` buffer before using `cin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never check whether reading was successful. A fundamental part of any programming is proper error handling. `std::cin >> selection;` will fail if a `char` cannot be read from the stream or set the `eofbit` if the end of the source is reached.

A simple way to check this is to use something like the following:

```
if (!(std::cin >> selection)) // Check if operation failed
{
    std::cout << "Failed to read!\n"; // Notify user
    std::cin.clear(); // Reset stream
    // Ignore rest of line
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: When entering an integer I type, for example, a '1' and press the enter key? Why does this not set the error flag?

Comment: @JSeith: Actually, I realized I cannot produce the problem you are having. Could you give the exact code and the exact input?

Comment: The exact code I've tested with is as above except you can comment out the switch statement and the while loop actually calls queryAction instead of the loop being inside of the function itself. And the input value is returned. The input is simply '?' + <press enter>

Comment: @JSeith: I just realized you said the `input value is returned`, note that you return an `int` from `queryAction`, not a `char`. Are you 100 percent sure you are reading `char`s and not `int` type?