# How to make function "run" work. The program just exits when run is called

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to make a login system (in progress) for a challenge(self), but the function "run" that returns a function, exits when called. Kindly assist

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
//initialise function pointer that is void and takes no parameter
typedef void (*funcpointer)();
//forward declare a function run that takes an integer parameter
funcpointer run(int op);
//declare class user with username and password
class User {
private:
    string m_name;
    string m_password;

public:
    //constructor for class
    User()
    {
    }
    //friend functions that need to access class members
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, User& user);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, User& user);
    friend void access();
    friend void display();
};
//vector that stores class
std::vector<User> m_user;
//allows user defined input of class members
istream& operator>>(istream& in, User& user)
{
    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    in >> user.m_name;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    in >> user.m_password;
    return in;
}
//ouputs Class member contents in user defined manner(allows cout << class)
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, User& user)
{
    out << "Username is: " << user.m_name << " Password is: " << user.m_password << '\n';
    return out;
}
//allows user to choose whether to log in, make ne user or view users
void logIn()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Would you like to: \n1: Make new user\n2: Log In\n3: Display users\n";
    do {
        cin >> num;
    } while ((num != 1) && (num != 2) && (num != 3));

    run(num);
}
void newUser()
{
    User x;
    cin >> x;
    m_user.push_back(x);
}
void access()
{

    string name, password;
    cout << "Enter username: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_user.size(); i++) {
        if (name == m_user[i].m_name) {
            cout << m_user[i].m_name << " found. Enter password: ";
            getline(cin, password);
            if (password == m_user[i].m_password) {
                cout << "access granted";
            }
            else
                cout << "Wrong password\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "Username not found!\n";
    }
}
void display()
{
    int count = 1;
    for (auto& users : m_user) {
        cout << count << ": " << users.m_name << '\n';
    }
}
//function run that returns function
funcpointer run(int op)
{
    switch (op) {
    default:
    case 1:
        return newUser;
    case 2:
        return access;
    case 3:
        return display;
    }
}

int main()
{

    logIn();

    return 0;
}
```

i expected the function num to call newUser when 1 is passed, but exits instead with 0
what could be the problem? i also tried changing the parameter to char and string with the same result

Comment: Your `LogIn()` does't do anything with the pointer returned from run. `run(num);` so your program ends. Note that run() does not run anything. It just returns a pointer to a function that the calling function needs to use to execute the returned function. The calling function in your case just ignores / throws away the pointer

Comment: Your function `run` just returns a function pointer, but you never call the function pointed to. Try `run(num)();`.

Comment: Be aware that you can drive `std::cin` into error state by invalid input that cannot be interpreted as a number (e. g. if containing letters). See e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14613243/1312382) how to get out.

Comment: By the way,, why don't you call those functions directly inside `run` function? `void run(int) { case 1: newUser(); break; }`?

Answer (score 0):

If you return funcpointer you probably want to call it. You could make it by writing () after funcpointer object like this `run(num)();`